# Probability that one player has all the card and one player has no card of spades?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, card-games

I am developing a 4 players AI based hearts game. Every player has random 13 cards of the 52 cards. I need some probabilities to make the AI.

- In the first move (Everyone has 13 cards), I have 4 cards of **Spades**. So, other 3 players have total 9 cards of **Spades**. What is the probability that at least one player has no **Spades**?
- In the first move (Everyone has 13 cards), I have 4 **Spades** (**3**, **4**, **J**, **K**). I want to play **K**, what is the probability of getting points (**Q** of **Spades** or any **Hearts**)?, remember that **A** of **Spades** **>** **K** of **Spades**.

Comment: what have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: How many ways are there that every player has a spade? Isn't it the partition of $9$ into $3$ parts. Which is same as the number of surjective maps from a $9$ elements set to a $3$ elements set.

Comment: I'm not good in probabilities & statistics. I thought for the first problem, no one has spades probability of **0**, one player has spades probability of **1/9**, two player have probability of **1/81**, everyone have spades probability of **1/3**.  is it correct? @supinf

Comment: @Dbchatto67 can you explain me more, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only answers your first question.

---

There are $39$ cards left for the other $3$ players and among them there are $9$ spades.

Each of them gets $13$ cards.

Number the other $3$ players and for $i=1,2,3$ let $E_i$ be the event that player $i$ gets no spades.

Applying the [principle of inclusion/exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) and symmetry we find that:$$P(E_1\cup E_2\cup E_3)=3P(E_1)-3P(E_1\cap E_2)=3\left[\frac{\binom{30}{13}}{\binom{39}{13}}-\frac{\binom{30}{4}}{\binom{39}{13}}\right]=$$$$\frac{3\left[\binom{30}{13}-\binom{30}{4}\right]}{\binom{39}{13}}\approx0.044223$$

Comment: Isn't 0.044223 the probability that no one gets Spades? I wanted at least one player who doesn't get Spades!

Comment: So, I subtract it from 1? 1-0.044223?

Comment: $0.044223$ is the probability that at least one of the  $3$ has no spades.

Comment: thanks, can you solve the second one please? I couldn't continue my game developing! :(

Comment: Sorry, but for that I must at least know the rules of the game. I am not a cardplayer and have absolutely no idea how it works. Your second question on its own does not make me wiser. Btw, don't interpret this as promise.

Comment: why 30C4/39C13 is used? what is that?

Comment: It is the probability that player 1 and 2 both have no spades ($P(E_1\cap E_2)$), or equivalently that player 3 has all remaining spades. So it equals $$\frac{\binom{30}{4}\binom{9}{9}}{\binom{39}{13}}=\frac{\binom{30}{4}}{\binom{39}{13}}$$You could also write it as:$$\frac{\binom{30}{26}\binom{9}{0}}{\binom{39}{13}}=\frac{\binom{30}{26}}{\binom{39}{13}}$$ which is the same.